# Program empty in System Status information for transaction SNOTE

Tags: abap

How can I view the source code for the transaction SNOTE? I use the system dialog (System -> Status -> Program name) but the "program" field is empty.

[image]

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so that it is understandable? I'd love to answer if I only knew what you want to know.

Comment: I want see how working (sourse code) SNOTE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the program associated with any transaction using the transaction **se93**. This will give you the program and, if needed, the selection-screen variant used.

You can then use the transactions se38 or se80. The later will give you at the same time the source code, classes and dynpro associated with the program.

Answer (score 0):

open the program SCWN_ENTRY_TREE in SE38